# How to structure a cnn for fine-tuning?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to fine-tune a model so that I can experiment with various different hyper parameters. For example:

- filters
- Regularisation
- Convolutional filter size
- Learning rate
- Optimizers

I have chose do do this in PyTorch and have created a base model (see below). However I am unsure of the best way to set up my code in order to do this. Specifically my ConvNet and train function. I will need to make comparisons as I go along using graphs. Could anyone offer any advice on the best way to structure my code/go about this.

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super().__init__()

    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    )

    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    )

    self.fcl = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(1152, 100)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = self.fcl(out)

    return out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple tutorial, PyTorch has one that is explained well for computer vision here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

This is section is most relevant to your question so you can see how fine-tuning is done when the optimizer is adjusted.

```py
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
# Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.
# Alternatively, it can be generalized to nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names)).
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
```

You have to train your model completely first. Then you can refer to this post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-perform-finetuning-in-pytorch/419/8?u=nullpointer

```py
ignored_params = list(map(id, model.fc.parameters()))
base_params = filter(lambda p: id(p) not in ignored_params,
                     model.parameters())

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([
            {'params': base_params},
            {'params': model.fc.parameters(), 'lr': opt.lr}
        ], lr=opt.lr*0.1, momentum=0.9)
```

If you'd like to change the weights of a layer without changing the weights of the network while you're fine-tuning, you can do something like the following:

```py
    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
    print list(list(model.classifier.children())[1].parameters())
    mod = list(model.classifier.children())
    mod.pop()
    mod.append(torch.nn.Linear(4096, 2))
    new_classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*mod)
    print list(list(new_classifier.children())[1].parameters())
    model.classifier = new_classifier
```

If you're looking to add layers or filters to the current model:

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model):
        self.pretrained_model = pretrained_model
        self.last_layer = ... # create layer

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.last_layer(self.pretrained_model(x))
```

Comment: Hello, if you found this helpful, please confirm this question has been answered. You can accept one answer (again, if it helps you) by clicking on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of a good answer, click the upper gray triangle and the points will be awarded accordingly.